# Derivative with constraint

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a function $$ Z=Z(\vec{\theta}, \vec{p})$$ and the vector $$ \vec{p}=[p_1,p_2...p_n]  $$ is a probability. I would like to compute the derivative $ \frac{\partial Z}{\partial \vec{p}} $  (in Matlab, I am using finite differences, $ \frac{\partial Z}{\partial {p_i}}= \frac{Z(p_i+h)-Z(p_i -h)}{2h} $). Given that the vector $\vec{p}$ has the constraint that $$ \vec{c}^T \vec{p}=1 $$  where c is a discretization vector to compute the integral of probability, how can I calculate the derivative of the function? For the sake of generalization, you can also reply using $ \vec{c}^T \vec{p}=\lambda $ .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a bit strange. $Z$ depends on $p$, and assuming you have an explicit form for $Z$, you can just differentiate it in each $p_i$. Or do it numerically. The constraint is immaterial, since the derivative of $Z$ works for any combination of $p_i$'s.

Comment: @AlexR. $ Z $ is the output of a complicated model that depends also on $ \vec{p} $. Numerically I calculate the derivative I am interested in using the finite difference method: I perturbate the $ i-th $ one component of $ \vec{p} $ with an increment h, I give this new vector of probabilities $ \vec{p_2} $  with the $ p_{2i} = p_i+h$  as input to the model that calculate the resultant $ Z $ and compute the derivative at the point i. What I mean is that when I perturbate the probability with the increment/decrement h, the integral is no more 1. Don't know if it's more clear now.